DNN Razor Host Module - How to use a querystring parameter as a variable to get data related to a specific UserID
I need a syntax help to write the following code to use in Host Razor module on a dnn site version 9.13.
I need to use a querystring parameter as a variable to get data related to a specific UserID.
@using DotNetNuke.Common;
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;
@{ 
    var userInfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo().UserID;
    var querystringuserid = Request.QueryString["userid"];
}
@querystringuserid
<br>
@UserController.GetUserById(0,3).DisplayName

till here it works
but I'm in trouble with the following code
@UserController.GetUserById(0,@querystringuserid).DisplayName

or the following
@UserController.GetUserById(0,Request.QueryString["userid"]).DisplayName


You have to convert the querystring to an integer:
@using DotNetNuke.Common;
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;
@{ 
   var userInfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo().UserID;
   var querystringuserid = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["userid"]);
}
@querystringuserid
<br />
@UserController.GetUserById(0 ,@querystringuserid).DisplayName

